# JWTDecodeException (Invalid JSON format)

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

I'm trying to use `com.auth0.jwt (3.8.1)` for implementing `JSON Web Tokens`, but it didn't work as expected.
The encoding works fine, but if I try to verify the encoded token I'm always getting an error:

> com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException: The string '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}' doesn't have a valid JSON format

even when I'm encoding in the same moment (see code `(function "verify")`), so it can't be altered between encoding and verifying.

Do I overlook something?

Here ist the token:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUZXN0QXV0aCIsImlhdCI6MTU2MjA2MDg4MywiZW1haWwiOiJURVNUQFRFU1RURVNULmRlIn0.A1dSRHLbevqC2lXSJ73kaaiMp7CD_MJCrs9vLBMGvng

```
package test.jwt;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.util.Date;

import com.auth0.jwt.*;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

public class TestJWT {
  final String SECRET = "sr4mkbbr4wdy45974s94l3squ0wtpf15";



  public String verify(String token) {
    try {
        token = this.encode();   //for testing      
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET)).withIssuer("TestAuth").build();

        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        return jwt.getClaim("email").asString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }

  public String encode() {
    try {

        return JWT.create().withIssuer("TestAuth").withIssuedAt(new Date()).withClaim("email", "TEST@TESTTEST.de").sign(getAlgorithm());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

  }

  private Algorithm getAlgorithm() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you pls. show us the token (click on edit to add it to your question)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that token. I checked it in https://jwt.io as well, no problem

Comment: I guess the token is not the problem. As you see in the code I create the token with
    **token = this.encode();**
and one step further I try to verify it, so it can't be modified between

Comment: I tried the same with **io.jsonwebtoken** but I got almost the same error:
**io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value: {"alg":"HS256"}**


I think slowly that I basically do something wrong.
Somebody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your token isn't valid JSON.

It needs '{' prepended and '}' appended to it.
I added those and it decoded fine.  I'm not sure if it will fix all of your problems, but it should fix the one in the title of this post.

[image]